# Compiling java code cannot find source files

Tags: java, javac

I am following exercise 1.2 of the Oracle Java SE 8 exam preparation which instructs me to build a main class `GreetingsUniverse` and three classes which will be initialised by the main class; `Mars`, `Earth` and `Venus`.

I have the `com` directory stored at location: `C:\Users\Chris\Documents\JavaMM`

```
package com.ocajexam.tutorial;

import com.ocajexam.tutorial.planets.Earth;
import com.ocajexam.tutorial.planets.Venus;
import com.ocajexam.tutorial.planets.Mars;

public class GreetingsUniverse
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Greetings, Universe!");
        Earth e = new Earth();
        Mars m = new Mars();
        Venus v = new Venus();
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.ocajexam.tutorial.planets;

public class Mars
{
    public Mars()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello from Mars!");
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.ocajexam.tutorial.planets;

public class Earth
{
    public Earth()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello from Earth!");
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.ocajexam.tutorial.planets;

public class Venus
{
    public Venus()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello from Venus!");
    }
}
```

The exercise aim is to determine the command line arguments required to compile the code.

I have the `GreetingsUniverse` java file stored in `com\ocajexam\tutorial\` and the planets store in `com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets`

I have tried various solutions with no success:

```
javac -d . -cp com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets com\ocajexam\tutorial\GreetingsUniverse.java

javac -d . -cp com com\ocajexam\tutorial\GreetingsUniverse.java
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\Chris\Documents\JavaMM>javac -d . -cp com com\ocajexam\tutorial\GreetingsUniverse.java
com\ocajexam\tutorial\GreetingsUniverse.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                Earth e = new Earth();
                ^
  symbol:   class Earth
  location: class GreetingsUniverse
com\ocajexam\tutorial\GreetingsUniverse.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                Earth e = new Earth();
                              ^
  symbol:   class Earth
  location: class GreetingsUniverse
com\ocajexam\tutorial\GreetingsUniverse.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                Mars m = new Mars();
                ^
  symbol:   class Mars
  location: class GreetingsUniverse
com\ocajexam\tutorial\GreetingsUniverse.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                Mars m = new Mars();
                             ^
  symbol:   class Mars
  location: class GreetingsUniverse
com\ocajexam\tutorial\GreetingsUniverse.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                Venus v = new Venus();
                ^
  symbol:   class Venus
  location: class GreetingsUniverse
com\ocajexam\tutorial\GreetingsUniverse.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                Venus v = new Venus();
                              ^
  symbol:   class Venus
  location: class GreetingsUniverse
6 errors
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong with this?

I have also tried the following which produces a different error message:

```
C:\Users\Chris\Documents\JavaMM>javac -d . com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets\Earth.java;com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets\Mars.java;com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets\Venus.java com\ocajexam\tutorial\GreetingsUniverse.java
```

Produces this error:

```
javac: file not found: com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets\Earth.java;com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets\Mars.java;com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets\Venus.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

The files are definitely there, if I dir on the `planets` directory I can see them there:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\Chris\Documents\JavaMM\com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets

16/10/2016  11:33    <DIR>          .
16/10/2016  11:33    <DIR>          ..
15/10/2016  21:48               135 Earth.java
15/10/2016  21:48               132 Mars.java
15/10/2016  21:48               135 Venus.java
```

Update:
After further debugging this is just getting stranger..

I am trying to compile only the planet files using the first half of the command:

```
javac -d . -cp com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets\*.java
```

When I check the planet directory, only two of the planets have compiled. When I remove the java class that isn't compiling, only 1 of the files is compiled!

When I use the same command specifying the java file I want to compile:

```
javac -d . -cp com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets\Venus.java
```

I get the following error:

```
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I can't make any sense of this because `Venus.java` was one of the files that did compile when I ran the `/*.java` compilation command to detect any java files in the directory

Comment: Your classpath is `.`, not `com`.

Comment: I have also tried that and get the same error

Comment: `Venus.java`, for example needs to be its own file. The formatting of your question does not make that very clear

Comment: What OS are you using?  I tried my command below on both windows and ubuntu to ensure that it would work.  If possible could you do cd com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets and then run ls or dir to get the directory contents and post them here?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Home. I did a `dir` of the directory the planet files are in:  `Directory of C:\Users\Chris\Documents\JavaMM\com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets` and it shows `Earth.class`, `Earth.java`, `Mars.class`, `Mars.java`, `Venus.class` and `Venus.java`

Comment: You said you tried the following:
javac -d . com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets\Earth.java;com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets\Mars.java;com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets\Venus.java com\ocajexam\tutorial\GreetingsUniverse.java
1. your format looks a little weird.  The semicolons should probably be spaces.
2.  You didn't define a source path(which can be defined by the class path) to fix this you would have to write -cp after -d . i.e. javac -d . -cp SOURCEFILES_HERE

Comment: I tried on my PC at work, Windows 7 and using Java 7 instead and it compiles fine. could this be something to do with Windows 10 and Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile all the classes first. The **javac** only compiles your main class. Use `javac -cp /path/to/file/*.java`. The asterisk (`*.java`) means to compile all java classes in the folder.

Comment: That's compiling those files ok but I still get the same error when I try to compile the main class

Comment: You don't need to manually compile every class if it's on the classpath. The compiler is smart enough to include other classes automatically.

Comment: Then I don't understand why it's throwing an error saying it cannot find them

Answer (score 0):

The example in the OCA Java SE 8 Programmer I Study Guide uses a constructor without parentheses.

```
package com.ocajexam.tutorial.planets;

    public class Earth { 
        public Earth { 
            System.out.println("Hello from Earth!"); 
        } 
    }
```

this should, of course, be

```
package com.ocajexam.tutorial.planets;

    public class Earth { 
        public Earth () { 
            System.out.println("Hello from Earth!"); 
        } 
    }
```

You can then run `javac com/ocajexam/tutorial/greetingsUniverse.java` and `java com/ocajexam/tutorial/GreetingsUniverse`.

Although strictly speaking this is not an answer to the question (which uses constructors with parentheses), it might help other people with the same error.

Answer (score -1):

All of the .java files used need to be on the classpath.  ie `javac -d . -cp com com\ocajexam\tutorial\*.java com\ocajexam\tutorial\planets\*.java`

Try doing: javac -d . -cp com com/ocajexam/tutorial/GreetingsUniverse.java com/ocajexam/tutorial/planets/Earth.java com/ocajexam/tutorial/planets/Mars.java com/ocajexam/tutorial/planets/Venus.java

Comment: I've tried this and am still getting the same error

Comment: You can't have sourcefiles on classpath at all, and classfile locations need to NOT include the package part of the path because that is added automatically.

Comment: Per: docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html 
If the -sourcepath option is not specified, the user class path is also searched for source files.